# Images and text that doesn't wrap without bootstrap?

Tags: html, css

For a web dev project I'm trying to format some images and text in a particular way with html/css, which I've been able to do with bootstrap, but I'd like to do so without bootstrap. I'd like to use this code as a template for multiple pages and while the bootstrap solution does what I'd like it to do, it does so only in one specific instance and won't work as well in others. 
Here's how I want it to look, without using bootstrap: 
`--------------heading--------------
-----image-----`  `-----text 1-----
-----text 2-----` 
The trick is that text 1 might sometimes be long enough to wrap around the bottom of the image, and I don't want that to happen. If text 1 is long enough that it goes farther down than the bottom of the image, I want it to function as if it were in its own column. I also want text 2 to be below the image, and justified all the way left.
Any help would be very much appreciated, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is make use of a row / column layout where the heading occupies an individual row. The second row would then be split into two columns - left and right. The left-most column would contain the image and `text 2`, while the right-most column would contain `text 1`. You would need to set a `width` of `50%` on both columns, and `float` them to the `left`.

This can be seen in the following, where I've added placeholder text and backgrounds to help illustrate this.

```css
.left,
.right {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}

.heading {
  background: lightsalmon;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
}

img {
  display: block;
  margin: 10px auto;
}

p {
  margin: 10px;
}

.left {
  background: yellow;
}

.right {
  background: cyan;
}
```

```html
<div class="row heading">Heading</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="left">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Condimentum vitae sapien pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et. Dictumst vestibulum rhoncus est pellentesque elit.
      Vestibulum lorem sed risus ultricies tristique nulla aliquet enim. Sapien pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada. Vitae tortor condimentum lacinia quis. Luctus venenatis lectus magna fringilla urna porttitor rhoncus
      dolor.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Condimentum vitae sapien pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et. Dictumst vestibulum rhoncus est pellentesque elit.
      Vestibulum lorem sed risus ultricies tristique nulla aliquet enim. Sapien pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada. Vitae tortor condimentum lacinia quis. Luctus venenatis lectus magna fringilla urna porttitor rhoncus
      dolor. Mauris vitae ultricies leo integer malesuada. Sed arcu non odio euismod. Id nibh tortor id aliquet lectus proin nibh. Tortor at risus viverra adipiscing. Platea dictumst quisque sagittis purus sit amet volutpat consequat mauris. In ornare
      quam viverra orci sagittis eu volutpat odio facilisis. Vel orci porta non pulvinar. Interdum velit euismod in pellentesque massa placerat. Euismod in pellentesque massa placerat duis ultricies lacus sed.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```